# Endless scrolling on table, infinite / continious scrolling jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook, jquery-ui, twitter, scroll

I have a table with lots of records, rather than have pagination to different pages, I want to be able to scroll down the page and for more rows to appear on the table, the more you scroll the more records you see.

Similar to how Twitter and Facebook work but for table rows. The scroller being the default scroll bar on the browser? I think its called endless scrolling?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

this is call load on scroll

few links that can give you a start

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/

http://thewebthought.blogspot.com/2012/01/jquery-loading-content-while-user.html

http://designbeep.com/2011/08/12/12-jquery-infinite-scrollingscroll-read-plugins-for-content-navigation/

Answer (score 1):

```
  var scroll = 0;
           $(window).scroll(function () {

               if (scroll > 0) {
                   if ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - 50)) {
                       getTableItems();   /*call this function for getting table items from database*/
                    }
               }
               scroll++;
           });
```

Above script will load more items on scroll

Comment: how would I add static content in to that function? I need to avoid php, asp, sql, coldfusion etc? Something like bringing in static table content from another html file or as you scroll the css display can be set to display:block???

Comment: You are not getting data from database? on scrolling, if you want to load more data from database, you may call Ajax in that function.